FastAPI SQLAlchemy TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute when querying joined tables
I'm building an API using FastAPI, SQLAlchemy, and PostgreSQL, and I encountered an issue when querying joined tables. Specifically, I have a route that retrieves products along with the count of associated votes using a left join. Here's a simplified version of the code:
@router.get("/")
def get_products(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    products = db.query(models.Product, func.count(models.Vote.product_id).label("votes")).join(
        models.Vote, models.Vote.product_id == models.Product.id, isouter=True).group_by(models.Product.id).all()
    
    return products

When I make a GET request to this endpoint, I get the following error:

ValueError: [TypeError('cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence'), TypeError('vars() argument must have dict attribute')]

This error specifically points to the vars() function call within FastAPI's jsonable_encoder function, suggesting that the objects returned from the query result are missing a __dict__ attribute required for serialization.
Interestingly, this issue only occurs when I query the joined tables (Product and Vote). Other queries, such as fetching a list of products or retrieving a single product, work fine without any errors.
When I print the products variable, I get the following output (There's only one item in the database):

[(<app.models.Product object at 0x7866fc2fee30>, 1)]

Here's the output that I expected on Postman:
{
    "Product": {
        "id":19,
        "is_available": true,
        "user_id": 3,
        "title": "Detergent",
        "price": 34,
        "created_at": "2024-06-22T00:09:11.151541+05:45",
    },
    "votes": 0
}

Could someone please help me understand why this error is happening and how I can resolve it? It seems to be related to how SQLAlchemy returns the result of joined queries, but I'm not sure how to fix it in the context of FastAPI.
Here's the whole traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 329, in jsonable_encoder
    data = vars(obj)
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 411, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 69, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 186, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 65, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 756, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 776, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 297, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 77, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 72, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 296, in app
    content = await serialize_response(
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 180, in serialize_response
    return jsonable_encoder(response_content)
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 303, in jsonable_encoder
    jsonable_encoder(
  File "/home/mr0bn0xi0us/projects/fastapi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 332, in jsonable_encoder
    raise ValueError(errors) from e
ValueError: [TypeError('cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence'), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]

Additional Information:

Python version: 3.10.12
FastAPI version: 0.111.0
SQLAlchemy version: 2.0.30
Pydantic version: 2.7.1
PostgreSQL version: 16.3

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You might find this answer helpful

It seems that if a FastAPI route has to return an arbitrary object, it tries to obtain a mapping of the object's public attributes by recursively calling vars on it, serialises the attributes to JSON and returns the JSON.
In this case, the object being returned is a list of [ORMEntity, int] tuples. Tuples do not have a __dict__ attribute because their attributes are stored in in __slots__, hence attempts to call vars on them fail:
>>> vars((1, 2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    vars((1, 2))
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

Since FastAPI's default behaviour cannot handle the tuples, you can take one of these actions:

manually construct the list of dicts to return
return [{'product': vars(p), 'count': c} for (p, c) in products


define a suitable Pydantic model (or suite of models) and use it as a Response Model
if you will frequently return the count, consider adding it to the model

